# Importing the main package crate from the tests directory of a cargo package

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am trying to see how to write unit tests for a rust executable that are not within a module of the same file, but rather in the `tests/` dir next to the `src/` generated by cargo. Currently, this is my directory setup

```
hello_cargo
        |
        src
          |
           main.rs
           value.rs
        tests
            |
             tests.rs
```

Contents of value.rs:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum Value {
    Int(i32),
    Bool(bool)
}
```

Contents of main.rs

```
mod value;

use value::Value;

fn main() {
    let x:Value = Value::Int(7);
    let y = Value::Bool(true);

    match x {
        Value::Int(ival) => println!("{}", ival),
        Value::Bool(bval) => println!("{}", bval)
    }

    match y {
        Value::Int(ival) => println!("{}", ival),
        Value::Bool(bval) => println!("{}", bval)
    }
}
```

contents of tests.rs

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::hello_cargo;
    #[test]
    fn it_works() {
        let y = value::Value::Bool(true);
        match y {
            value::Value::Bool(val) => assert!(val),
            _ => ()
        }
    }
}
```

When i run `cargo test`, i always get, with multiple different `use::` combinations

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `super::hello_cargo`
 --> tests/tests.rs:5:6
  |
5 |     use super::hello_cargo;
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ no `hello_cargo` in the root
```

Is it not possible to do this with executables? Do you need a library in order to have tests in the external test directory?

Would this be solved by wrapping all the code in each file in a `mod`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out the code below in the `tests/` dir

```
use hello_cargo;

// This needs to be in the /tests/ dir beside /src/
// the above `use` must match the name of the crate itself.

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    #[test]
    fn it_works() {
        let y = hello_cargo::value::Value::Bool(true);
        match y {
            hello_cargo::value::Value::Bool(val) => assert!(val),
            _ => ()
        }
    }

}
```

The `use` statement has to just be the name of the crate the current package produces, without any `super` or `self` prefixing

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Do you have this in a public repository? Could you drop a link to it?

Comment: @Michael Either the OP forgot to mention this or it has changed in the meantime. You cannot import from main.rs. Instead, rename main.rs to lib.rs and rename the main function. Then if you need a main create a main.rs and call your renamed function from there.